# How coroutine_handle<Promise>::from_promise() works in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I [read](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2018/09/05/understanding-the-promise-type) that `coroutine_handle` can be reconstructed from a reference to the coroutine's promise object using `coroutine_handle<Promise>::from_promise()` function. To my knowledge, the promise object is defined like this:

```cpp
class resumable{
public:
  struct promise_type;
  bool resume();
};

struct resumable::promise_type{
  resumable get_return_object() {/**/}
  auto initial_suspend() {/**/}
  auto final_suspend() {/**/}
  void return_void() {}
  void unhandled_exception();
};
```

I am failing to figure out how reconstruction could work given the fact that `promise_type` doesn't hold any reference to the coroutine handle. Just the opposite, the coroutine handle stores the reference to the promise object, which can be returned by the `promise()` method of the handle. I can't find any information on what actually happens in `from_promise` function.

Comment: It's compiler magic.  Other things that need compiler magic are std::initializer_list and std::has_trivial_constructor and std::has_virtual_destructor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works by fiat. That is, it works because the standard *says* that it works, and implementations must therefore find a way to implement coroutines in such a way that it is possible.

When creating a coroutine, the implementation creates two things: the `coroutine_handle` (or rather, the guts of it to which the `coroutine_handle` points) and the promise object. The location of both of these things is controlled entirely by the compiler. So, the compiler could very easily allocate them contiguously with each other, such that a coroutine's stack would essentially start with a `struct {coroutine_guts handle; Promise promise};`, where `coroutine_guts` is the object that the `coroutine_handle` points to.

Given that knowledge, you know that the handle for any promise type lives `sizeof(coroutine_guts)` bytes before any `promise` object's address (alignment requirements of the `Promise` type can adjust this, but such things can be queried from the type). And since `from_promise` takes a promise object, you can just offset the pointer to get the `coroutine_guts` and shove that in a `coroutine_handle<Promise>`.

Now, that is just one way of doing it; an implementation doesn't have to do it this way. What matters is that the implementation has control over where the promise object lives relative to the coroutine internal data. Or more specifically, the promise lives *inside* of that internal data. Regardless of how you look at it, the compiler knows everything it needs to in order to convert the address of a promise into the internal data needed to fill in a `coroutine_handle`.